# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{2n+2-k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}=\frac1{2k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to show that the following statement holds for every $k\in\mathbb{N}^*$:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{2n+2-k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}=\frac1{2k}$$

The original proof is via an extremely long work with digamma functions and complex numbers. For this reason I wondered if a more straightforward proof can be obtained withouth imaginary numbers and special functions.

For this reason I thought **induction** would do the job. However, when dealing with the inductive step, I supposed that for some $k\ge 1$ the equality holds, and I looked at the $k+1$ case.

Here comes the issue: plugging in $k+1$ instead of $k$ turns the summand in something that is not related to the previous case (apart from having $k+1$ instead of $k$)
\begin{align}
& k: &&& \frac{2n+2-k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2} \\
\\
& k+1: &&& \frac{2n+1-k}{(2n+1-k)^2+(k+1)^2} \\
\end{align}
so I couldn't **use the inductive hypothesis**, since it is a different sum from before.

To make the matter clear, we know that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{2n+2-k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}=\frac1{2k}$$
but I can't see how to use this fact in the evaluation of
$$\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{2n+1-k}{(2n+1-k)^2+(k+1)^2}$$
since the **denominators are different**.

Any ideas on how to prove the statement?

Comment: Can the sum not be done explicitly? Try the substitution $m=2n+2-k$, do a lot of terms then not cancel out leaving the  $m=k$ term?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure on how to do it, can you consider writing an answer with more details if your method works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly let remove $+2$ by increasing $n$ by $1$:
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{k - 1}\frac{2n + 2 - k}{(2n + 2 - k)^2 + k^2} = \sum_{n = 1}^{k}\frac{2n - k}{(2n - k)^2 + k^2}.$$
Now note that
$$\frac{2n - k}{(2n - k)^2 + k^2} + \frac{k - 2n}{(k - 2n)^2 + k^2} = 0.$$
Therefore we can match each summand with negative numerator to its positive sibling, which annihilates it. Also there is one positive summand which doesn't match to any negative one, and for even $k$ there is one summand with zero numerator:
$$\begin{aligned}&\sum_{n = 1}^{k}\frac{2n - k}{(2n - k)^2 + k^2}\\
=& \sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k - 1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{2n - k}{(2n - k)^2 + k^2} + [2 \mid k]\cdot \frac{2\frac{k}{2} - k}{(2\frac{k}{2} - k)^2 + k^2} + \sum_{n = \left\lceil\frac{k + 1}{2}\right\rceil}^{k - 1}\frac{2n - k}{(2n - k)^2 + k^2} + \frac{2k - k}{(2k - k)^2 + k^2}\\
=& \sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k - 1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{2n - k}{(2n - k)^2 + k^2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k - 1}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{2(k - n) - k}{(2(k - n) - k)^2 + k^2} + \frac{k}{2k^2}\\
=& \sum_{n = 1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k - 1}{2}\right\rfloor}\left(\frac{2n - k}{(2n - k)^2 + k^2} + \frac{k - 2n}{(k - 2n)^2 + k^2}\right) + \frac{1}{2k}\\
=& \frac{1}{2k}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Just one question: when you write $[2 \mid k]$ what do you mean?

Comment: [2|k]=1 if k is even and [2|k]=0 if k is odd

Comment: @Zima It is called Iverson notation or Iverson bracket: $[P] = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $P$},\\\boldsymbol{0} & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$ This zero is "stronger" than usual zero, it means just removing summand or whatever. Being multiplied by infinity or undefined value it remains to be zero. At the same time $a \mid b$ means that $a$ divides $b$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $k$ is even and odd respectively, separately, do the trivial calculations, and conclude the sum, in the general form, can be put into that form. **Q.E.D.**

For example, assuming $k$ even, I'll make abuse of the notation considering $2k$ (instead of other letters), and notice that

$$\sum _{n=0}^{2 k-1} \frac{2 n-2 k+2}{(2 n-2 k+2)^2+(2 k)^2}=\frac{1}{2} \sum _{n=1-k}^k \frac{n}{k^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{2\cdot 2k},$$  and now I hope everything is crystal clear.

Surely, in a similar style,  for the odd case, we have
$$\sum _{n=0}^{2 k-2} \frac{2 n-2 k+3}{(2 n-2 k+3)^2+(2 k-1)^2}=\sum _{n=2-k}^k \frac{2n-1}{(2k-1)^2+(2n-1)^2}=\frac{1}{2\cdot (2k-1)},$$
and the contribution comes from the last term of the second sum.

**End of story** (Thanks Cornel for the nice idea)

Answer (score 1):

In the sum $$S:=\sum_{n = 1}^{k }\frac{2n  - k}{(2n  - k)^2 + k^2} \quad(1)$$ substitute $m:=k-n.$ We obtain
$2n-k=-(2m-k),$ hence
$$S=\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}{-(2m-k)\over(2m  - k)^2 + k^2}=-
\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}{2n-k\over(2n  - k)^2 + k^2} \quad (2) $$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ the terms $1\le n\le k-1$ cancel and we obtain
$$2S={2k-k\over (2k-k)^2+k^2}-{0-k\over (0-k)^2+k^2}={1\over k}$$

Comment: Most elegant solution for now, thank you.